# How to extract a value from an array depending on its indice

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have 3 arrays. The first one contains strings considered as "forbidden". 
The second one contains random words (initially a message) where some of these words can be referenced in the first array.
And the third array contains numbers.

What I want to do is first to compare the two first arrays to check what words in my message (second array) are "forbidden" words (first array), and then, adding to a variable the numbers of the third array that actually correspond to the forbidden words as follows:

array1: dog cat horse

array3: 40 60 10

array2: I like my dog

I think I managed to achieve the first step with this piece of script:

```
array1=(dog cat horse)
array2=(I like my dog)
array3=(40 60 10)

myarray=()

for item1 in "${array1[@]}"; do
    for item2 in "${array2[@]}"; do
        if  [[ $item1 == $item2 ]]; then
            myarray+=( $item1 )
            break
        fi
    done
done

echo ${myarray[@]}
```

Result:

```
dog
```

But I still can't find a way to include my third array and extract the numbers that have the same indice as the forbidden words in the first array concerned by the message.

Comment: You use arrays `montab1` and `montab2` that aren't declared anywhere, are those supposed to be `array1` and `array2` instead? And what is the desired output regarding the numbers you want to extract from `array3`?

Comment: What should the expected output be? `40 40 40 dog`?

Comment: Thanks it's indeed array1 and array2 (i corrected it). What I'd like to have is a the value of the sum of all the numbers corresponding to the forbidden words that I've been able to find in my message. With my example I'd like to have a value myvalue=40 because the forbidden word found is dog corresponds to 40 in my array3

Comment: And if the message was "I like my dog and my horse" the value would be myvalue=50 because dog corresponds to 40 and horse to 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to iterate over the **indices** of the array, not the array elements:

```sh
sum=0
for i in "${!array1[@]}"; do    # note the `!` there
  forbidden=${array[i]}
  for word in "${array2[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$word" == "$forbidden" ]]; then
      (( sum += ${array3[i]} ))
    fi
  done
done
echo $sum
```

---

Another approach is to use an *associative* array: That maps the animal to the value quite directly as opposed to 2 separate arrays. As a bonus, it does not require nested loops.

```sh
declare -A forbidden=([dog]=40 [cat]=60 [horse]=10)
message=(I like my dog)
sum=0

for word in "${message[@]}"; do
  if [[ -n "${forbidden[$word]}" ]]; then
    (( sum += ${forbidden[$word]} ))
  fi
done
```

You should try to use more descriptive variable names than `array1` etc